# Solving an "integral equation" via recursion

Tags: numerical-methods, matlab, recursion, mathematica, programming

My problem is that I want to solve the integral equation
$$
f\left(t\right) = K\left\lbrace e^{\int_{t}^{T}\left(\alpha + \beta f(s) + \sigma f^2(s)\right)ds} + \gamma e^{-\frac{1}{2}\int_{t}^{T} \sigma f^2(s) ds} - \gamma \right\rbrace,
$$
where $K,\alpha,\beta,\sigma,\gamma >0$ are all constants. One can show that if we construct a sequence $\left\lbrace f_n(t) \right\rbrace_{n\geq 0}$ with $f_0=1$ and
$$
f_{n+1}(t) = K\left\lbrace e^{\int_{t}^{T}\left(\alpha + \beta f_n(s) + \sigma f_n^2(s)\right)ds} + \gamma e^{-\frac{1}{2}\int_{t}^{T} \sigma f_n^2(s) ds} - \gamma \right\rbrace,
$$
it converges, $f_n \to f$ as $n\to \infty$. That is, we can solve the initially stated equation numerically by iteration starting from $f_0=1$.

My question is, how would you perform these iterations? I tried writing a Matlab algorithm, and it can't handle more than 3 iterations. Mathematica stops at 4.

Comment: You are doing it recursively? What error does matlab or mathematica give? I am knowledgeable in programming and the error might yield a reason as to why the recursion fails.

Comment: what does $K$ mean?

Comment: The problem seem to be that it can't generate the full fourth symbolic expression,  so it stops and gives "symengine" error. Let me run it again to give you the exact error message. But it will take som time :)

Comment: Sorry, $K>0$ is just a constant.

Comment: well, if you use matlab to do numerical computation, why you use symbolic method?

Comment: How would you suggest that I should do it? I might have "tunnel-vision" here, but each $f_n$ is a function of time, which is one of the integral bounds ($t$), that makes me think that this must be the only way. Please enlighten me, I've been stuck with this for several weeks now

Comment: Just a note: It might be better to use the $\exp(\mathrm{bla})$ function instead of $e^{\mathrm{bla}}$ for ease of reading.